# In a possible Guided Strike vs. a possible Shield spell, who has to declare first?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, paladin, unearthed-arcana

The Unearthed Arcana Paladin class ability "Channel Divinity: Guided Strike" says:

> **Guided Strike**. You can use your Channel Divinity to strike with supernatural accuracy. When you make an attack roll, you can use your Channel Divinity to gain a +10 bonus to the roll. You make this choice after you see the roll, but
>   before the DM says whether the attack hits or misses.

When a paladin strikes an opponent who is able to cast *Shield*, who has to announce first whether Guided Strike/Shield is used? I am assuming I cannot wait until the DM announces whether he uses *Shield* or not to announce my own Guided Strike?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

## The Paladin calls it first

Guided Strike has to be used before the attack is declared a hit or miss. The Shield spell can be used after the attack hits (so it will always turn a hit into a miss, if used correctly).

> **Shield**
>
> *Casting Time*: 1 reaction, which you take *when you are hit by an attack* [...]

You use Shield after the DM has declared the hit. Contrast this with Guided Strike:

> You make this choice after you see the roll, but *before the DM says whether the attack hits or misses*.

Answer (score 14):

> **Casting Time**: 1 reaction, which you take **when you are hit** by an attack... - *PHB*, p275, emphasis mine.

You cannot wait until after the *Shield* is announced, because your decision has to come *before* the hit is announced, and *Shield* comes *after*.

> Until the start of your next turn, you have a +5 bonus to AC, **including against the triggering attack**...- *ibid*

*Shield* is retroactive, *guided strike* is not.